# Inject cancellation-token to the Configure Method in Startup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cancellation-token

Is it possible in .net core to inject a cancellation-token to the Configure Method in Startup? And does it get called when the application is canceled?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ILogger<Startup> logger, CancellationToken ct)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    _foo = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<foo>();
    app._foo.load(ct);

    ...
}
```

Comment: You can use a `IHostedService` to stop running tasks. It is a kind of IDisposable but gets disposed by IIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get `IHostApplicationLifetime` from `ApplicationServices` and use `ApplicationStopping`.

```
var hostApplicationLifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();

_foo = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<foo>();
app._foo.load(hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping);
```